# Debugging a Python for loop using breakpoints

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, debugging, web-scraping

I'm writing a Python Script for a scraping project, using bs4.

1. The script gives me an "**IndexError**", after a few pages scraped. In order to solve that I modified the code and put an incremental variable in a "for loop", specifically in a higher level category who contain the pages. With this I reduced in at least 1/2 the amount of time.
2. Now, with this "**bypass solution**", I found that still have to wait a lot of time.
3. Here it comes to me the solution of breakpoints and debugging. But here it's the main problem: how to debug a for loop to start from the beginning **without losing the incremental variable?**

Consider I'm using PyCharm/Spyder.

1. Read a lot of this topics, without find any solution
2. View a lot of youtube vids tutorial
3. Put and remove breakpoints in the gutter.

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from fake_headers import Headers
branked_c0,link_ranked_c0,q_a_c0,condition_soldnumber_c0,price_tag_c0,link_image_c0,link_product_c0,number_sales_seller_c0,name_product_c0=[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]
original_link="https://mercadolibre.cl/categorias#menu=categories"
req=requests.get(original_link,headers=Headers().generate())
soup=BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')
main=soup.select(".categories__container")[12] #bloque de categorias ##
sub_links=[]
end_="_Desde_{}"
for sbc in main:
    title_main=sbc.nextSibling
    print(type(title_main))
    print(len(title_main.contents))
    for i in range(0, len(title_main.contents)):
        print(i)
        subaru=title_main.contents[int(i)]
        print(subaru)
        for xo in subaru("a"):
             nombre_subcat = xo.string
             link_subcat = xo.get("href")
             print(link_subcat)
             sub_links.append(link_subcat)
             print(sub_links)
             for link in sub_links:
                 req = requests.get(link.format(0), headers=Headers().generate())
                 print(str(link) + str(nombre_subcat) + " = link s/nº")
                 soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
                 try:
                     page_count=soup.select(".andes-pagination__page-count")[0]
                     total_count=(page_count.text.split(" "))[-1]
                 except:
                     page_count = 0
                 print(str(page_count) + " = número de página de la subcategoría")
                 # -#print(str(total_count)+"= número total de páginas de la categoría")
                 count = 51
                 for page_no in range(int(total_count)):  
                     req = requests.get(link.format(count),headers=Headers().generate())
                     soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
                     sbc = soup.select(".ui-search-item__group.ui-search-item__group--title")```
````

Comment: What is the "gutter"?

Comment: In PyCharm gutter is the margin between the line number and the text-code editor where you write your script. This gutter works for activate/deactivate breakpoints.

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you want - but I think you can't restart `for`-loop with old values.